# Load an array into a multi column grid in Android

Tags: java, android, gridview, multidimensional-array

I have some data I retrieve from different databases and I need to display them in a grid on a android tablet. I have search everywhere but most of the Grid question is about images. I have four column in the grid the first three is strings and the last is dollar amount.
I'm confused how to load it into an array and then get the array into the grid. I'm and old Pascal programmer and in Pascal I would make an array myArray[4][], but I haven't been able to find any examples like this. I know how to get the data. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Start with `adapter` first. http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html
And what you are after is an item template with either TableLayout/RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Custom Adapter for that.

The example is given here :

[Click here](http://oudomvilla.wordpress.com/2010/08/23/create-icon-with-text-using-gridview-and-layout-inflater/)

If you have any doubt, ask me. I'll help you

Comment: I have no image in my grid just text and money.

Comment: Here is what i have to do: Get the data for each cell from a database, I would have to keep this in an array with four column, when finish getting the data I will have to display it in a grid, it almost look like a bank statement: first row would be any prior balance then each row will have each now order and the final row would have the total of the fourth column.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Kim,

```
        You need to make your customised row.
```

means Take Image view and Text view for showing image and text. According to your look and feel. and set the images and text according to your array list.

for more information see this Link [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531104/how-to-add-text-view-in-gridview-in-android-xml)